# paypal api country codes json or xml or something, anything?

Tags: paypal

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/country_codes/

lists the country_codes available for use with PayPal Express.  That's fine and dandy, but not exactly code friendly!  I see no actual API call that presents my server with this information.  What am I missing?  Do I really have to manually type in that list and manually check periodically to make sure nothing's changed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to PayPal support... nope, only way is to manually do it.  Granted, geopolitical scenes aren't changing THAT rapidly, and PayPal probably tends to align itself with the more stable list, but still I expected better.  I should be able to set a cron that checks periodically against a nicely formatted JSON, etc, so I can automatically update the country list used by my sites.  That way 5 years from now I don't have to find out that 4 years earlier I started unnecessarily missing business because PayPal opened up their services to Antarctica's hot bed of ecommerce activity.